# Can Jquery load method be used for getting data from PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, zend-server

I am using zend framework project which is been created by using zend studio. 
Also there is a Jquery project which is created separately.

I have deployed jquery project in tomcat, and on click of one button in jquery, a php method is called by using ajax **LOAD** method. PHP is returning string value.

However, for some reason data is not coming back to jquery method.

```
 Jquery method:




 var res =  $('#updatedtime').load("http://test/index/returndate");
```

---

```
PHP method

public function returndateAction(){
  $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);//this will do job

   return "hi";

 }
```

Can we use jquery LOAD method be used  to get data? Please correct me if am wrong!

Thanks all

Comment: Do you want to display the data directly on the page, or manipulate it from JS first? The [`.load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is intended to load content directly into an element (in your case that would be the `'#updatedtime'` element). To get a string from the server for use in JS try the [`$.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) (or `$.ajax()`, etc.). The jQuery doco has examples.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:
PHP

```
public function returndateAction(){
  $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);//this will do job
  echo "hi";
}
```

jQuery

```
// data from PHP is displayed in your element having id updatedtime
$('#updatedtime').load("http://test/index/returndate");
```

OR

```
$('#updatedtime').load("http://test/index/returndate", function(data){
    alert(data); //shows 'hi'
});
```

Check if the url you are trying to access thru load actually gets called.

Comment: / data from PHP is displayed in your element having id updatedtime
$('#updatedtime').load("http://test/index/returndate"); , this one. URL working fine, if it is accessed directly

Comment: if you are testing in local, then shouldn't the url be like: http://localhost/test/index/returndate ...?

Answer (score 0):

The client doesn't know or care what you run server side.  You can get anything you want from the server, whether that is something created with PHP, or a static resource.

If you aren't getting data back, use your browser's network tools to verify that the request is being made, and data is being returned.  Also, make sure you are actually executing that function server-side.  It doesn't appear that you are.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add a callback function as the second argument to [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$('#updatedtime').load("http://test/index/returndate", function (phpString) { ... });
```

Comment: Why would he need to use a callback here?